# Get clientID for multi userControl with same Server ID

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have ASP.Net application that have multiple User Controls in the same page every one have its hidden field that holds a value, and every one have button that calls pop-up and through this value from hidden field to it.
The problem that when i try to access the hidden field and get the value inside , the program always get the last one (which created last).
How can i get the value of the inner hidden field in the current UserControl (Which i'm clicking the button from)?
Attempts:

```
var hdnRegion = "<%=hdnRegionId.ClientID%>";
var regionIdVal = $("#" + hdnRegion).val();
methodName(regionIdVal);
```

another one:

```
var currentControl = "<%=this.ClientID%>";
var hdnRegion = currentControl + "_" + "hdnRegionId";
var regionIdVal = $("#" + hdnRegion).val();
methodName(regionIdVal);
```

I also tried to call a property from code behind that returns the value and one that returns the whole control with no correct result.

***Any suggestions would be appreciated...***

Comment: I know your answer, just put the part of aspx code that include `Button` and `HiddenField` that needed to provide you the exact answer.

Comment: <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRegionId" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" OnClientClick="return updateVals();" />
Note: This two controls exist in UserControl that exist for 4 or more times in a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accourding to your comment under the question, your `btnUpdate` and `hdnRegionId` controls are in the same container (for instance in the same `div`) so try this:

```
$('input[id*="btnUpdate"]').click(function(){
    var regionIdVal = $(this).parent().children('input[id*="hdnRegionId"]').val();
    methodName(regionIdVal);
});
```

This is a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sequk7e9/2/) that simulate your HTML code that is rendered by ASP.NET.